# Bootstrap three sibling columns, 2nd column aligned to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three divs, "First", "Second" and "Third". They are siblings (have the same parent), because on mobile they should simply appear under each other in this exact order.

On larger devices, I want First and Third to be on the left, and Second to be on the right.
The code below illustrates this, you can also see how it looks at http://www.bootply.com/mh9VFWxvp2.

My problem is the vertical space between the First and Third div. The Third div vertically aligns with the bottom of the Second div. I want Third to start right under First vertically, without leaving a block of empty space there. How to achieve this?

```
<div class="container-fluid">

 <div class="col-md-7" id="first">
  <h1>First</h1>                                
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu.
  </p>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-5" id="second">
   <h1>Second</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu. Ex congue probatus pericula ius, ei cum placerat persequeris. Nec sumo petentium forensibus ei. Noster impedit has ex. Ius te scripta volumus mentitum, lucilius recusabo argumentum eos id. Errem equidem constituto ei eam.</p>       
   <p>Aliquid placerat sit ad, eu mollis ornatus deterruisset eum. Consequat dissentiet definitiones at his. Et nostrum quaerendum omittantur pri. Per te verear admodum. Sed alia aliquid expetendis ea. Per et prima nostrud, et possim iuvaret suavitate vel, at pro brute primis. At eam suas democritum, te meis legere nam.</p>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-7" id="third">
  <h1>Third</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu. Ex congue probatus pericula ius, ei cum placerat persequeris. Nec sumo petentium forensibus ei. Noster impedit has ex. Ius te scripta volumus mentitum, lucilius recusabo argumentum eos id. Errem equidem constituto ei eam.</p>      
 </div>
</div>
```

Update: This was missing from the original question, but I'm trying to achieve the results without hiding (and duplication of code) if possible.

Comment: You can Check my answer you will get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pull-right` class on the second div. This will make it align to the right of the other columns.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-7" id="first">
  <h1>First</h1>                                
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu.
  </p>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-5 pull-right" id="second">
  <h1>Second</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu. Ex congue probatus pericula ius, ei cum placerat persequeris. Nec sumo petentium forensibus ei. Noster impedit has ex. Ius te scripta volumus mentitum, lucilius recusabo argumentum eos id. Errem equidem constituto ei eam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Aliquid placerat sit ad, eu mollis ornatus deterruisset eum. Consequat dissentiet definitiones at his. Et nostrum quaerendum omittantur pri. Per te verear admodum. Sed alia aliquid expetendis ea. Per et prima nostrud, et possim iuvaret suavitate vel, at pro brute primis. At eam suas democritum, te meis legere nam.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-7" id="third">
  <h1>Third</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu. Ex congue probatus pericula ius, ei cum placerat persequeris. Nec sumo petentium forensibus ei. Noster impedit has ex. Ius te scripta volumus mentitum, lucilius recusabo argumentum eos id. Errem equidem constituto ei eam.
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

**Updated: http://bootply.com/YJ1KxGIcBx**

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine. But I don't know this way is correct or not.

But It will give solution for your question. Other than Div section occupies 100% width on screen

```
#first, #third
{
  height:auto;
  float:left;
}
#second{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I chose Skelly's answer rather, because it uses Bootstrap classes, but basically this is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Now your both problems have been soled in this example. The problem of mobile as well in large screen. I have made two different div, first is for large screen which will hide in mobile and using hidden-sm class and second div is only display in mobile. You can check this.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid hidden-sm">
<div class="col-md-7">
 <div class="col-md-7" class="first">
   <h1>First</h1>                                
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7" class="third">
   <h1>Third</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu. Ex congue probatus pericula ius, ei cum placerat persequeris. Nec sumo petentium forensibus ei. Noster impedit has ex. Ius te scripta volumus mentitum, lucilius recusabo argumentum eos id. Errem equidem constituto ei eam.</p>      
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5" class="second">
   <h1>Second</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu. Ex congue probatus pericula ius, ei cum placerat persequeris. Nec sumo petentium forensibus ei. Noster impedit has ex. Ius te scripta volumus mentitum, lucilius recusabo argumentum eos id. Errem equidem constituto ei eam.</p>       
   <p>Aliquid placerat sit ad, eu mollis ornatus deterruisset eum. Consequat dissentiet definitiones at his. Et nostrum quaerendum omittantur pri. Per te verear admodum. Sed alia aliquid expetendis ea. Per et prima nostrud, et possim iuvaret suavitate vel, at pro brute primis. At eam suas democritum, te meis legere nam.</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid visible-sm" >
 <div class="col-sm-12" class="first">
    <h1>First</h1>                                
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu.
    </p>
   </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" class="second">
     <h1>Second</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu. Ex congue probatus pericula ius, ei cum placerat persequeris. Nec sumo petentium forensibus ei. Noster impedit has ex. Ius te scripta volumus mentitum, lucilius recusabo argumentum eos id. Errem equidem constituto ei eam.</p>       
     <p>Aliquid placerat sit ad, eu mollis ornatus deterruisset eum. Consequat dissentiet definitiones at his. Et nostrum quaerendum omittantur pri. Per te verear admodum. Sed alia aliquid expetendis ea. Per et prima nostrud, et possim iuvaret suavitate vel, at pro brute primis. At eam suas democritum, te meis legere nam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" class="third">
   <h1>Third</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, propriae accusata sea cu. Ex congue probatus pericula ius, ei cum placerat persequeris. Nec sumo petentium forensibus ei. Noster impedit has ex. Ius te scripta volumus mentitum, lucilius recusabo argumentum eos id. Errem equidem constituto ei eam.</p>      
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this is a solution, but I'm trying to achieve the results without duplication & hiding.

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific styles for larger devices using media queries

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
 #second {position: absolute; right: 0;}
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyrophdx/)